# X {..} <- getYesod notation

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm seeing this kind of notation all over sample code for Yesod web applications and have no idea what it means:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    App {..} <- getYesod
```

What does this syntax mean?

I'm also seeing the following, I assume related, notation:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    App x <- getYesod
```

i.e. Some identifier `x` in place of the cryptic `{..}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are called [record wildcards](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) - given a record definition (`App` in this case), the pattern `App { .. }` brings all the field names into scope. For example given the following record definition

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
data Test = Test { a :: Int, b :: Int }
```

you can match on it in a pattern, bringing the `a` and `b` fields into scope e.g.

```
sumTest :: Test -> Int
sumTest Test {..} = a + b
```

Comment: You can link directly to a section in the GHC documentation. For example: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards